# Is it possible to store custom values in my HttpContext.User.Claims and how do I fetch it?

Tags: c#, claims-based-identity, httpcontext, claimsprincipal

I tried creating a custom ClaimsPrincipal value "test" like below but received an error saying something like this value doesn't exist when trying to fetch it with GetTest().

```
var claims = new List<Claim>
{
    new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Email, user.Email),
    new Claim("test", user.Id.ToString() + "_" + user.UserName + "_" + user.Email)
};

var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
{
    Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
    ...
};

var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
string token =  tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
```

Then accessing it like this fails

```
var test = HttpContext.User.GetTest();

public static int GetTest(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    return int.Parse(user.FindFirst("test")?.Value);
}
```

I can access email claims no problem like this

```
public static string GetUserEmail(this ClaimsPrincipal user)
{
    return user.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
}
```

Comment: How is the user providing this token? Do you have an authentication scheme which will unpack the token into claims?

Comment: yes, I didn't post all the code. Didn't think that part was necessary

Comment: Also be aware of `JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap` which will be used to rename common claim names from JWT tokens to their typical MS equivalents.

Comment: I'm not sure what that is, but I'm not using it in my code base

Comment: I'm mentioning that because the default behaviour has tripped me up before. In other words, is the claim you are looking for in the collection under an unexpected name? Have you debugged the raw list of claims in the principal?

Comment: Note that `tokenHandler.CreateToken(...)` does translate some claim names. If your claim is in this list https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens/ClaimTypeMapping.cs#L9, it will be modified. (see https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/5068c6eaf1c87cf3fac7fb7411bbaee7ded8baa4/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs#L643) And the default behaviour of the JWT auth scheme will rename it back.